# Use Aspect to add response headers to all controllers

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, aop, spring-aop

I would like all of my Spring MVC controllers to include some common response headers.

I could do this using the following (Kotlin):

```
@ModelAttribute
open fun responseHeaders(response: HttpServletResponse)
{
    //identify the node that serviced the call
    response.setHeader("host-name", InetAddress.getLocalHost().hostName);
    //etc
}
```

. . since it applies to all, I could use a base-class. But is there a suggested way to use an Aspect instead?

Comment: Use a `Filter` or `HandlerInterceptor` for that.

Comment: Looks like HandlerInterceptor not great: http://stackoverflow.com/q/246762/404201 . . perhaps a filter

Comment: Do it in the preHandle instead of postHandle as that might be too late to set a header as the response might already be committed. The same will apply for a filter. Yu cannot modify the response once part of it has been returned to the user.

Comment: ah, i ended up just using a filter. but noted.